# How to create consumer dedicated to a topic ondemand (dynamically)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a usecase where i want to create topic and its consumer on demand i.e, when i host a product-1 for sale it should create a topic and consumer for product-1 and if i create product-2 it should create a topic and consumer for product-2.

[image]

creation of topic and consumer should be on-demand so that the traffic on one product should not affect other.

Im able to create new topic on demand and push new task to that topic and able to read it from same consumer which i have configured to read from dynamic topics using pattern, but stuck at creating consumer dedicated for that new topic on the go

can anyone please help me on how to create consumers on the go subscribing to a topic?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: @OneCricketeer im able to create new topic on demand and push new task to that topic and able to read it from same consumer which i have configured to read from dynamic topics using pattern, but stuck at creating consumer dedicated for that new topic on the go.

Comment: You can create `new KafkaConsumer()` and `subscribe("new-topic")`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you originally tagged this question with [spring-kafka](/questions/tagged/spring-kafka) (@OneCricketeer removed the tag; I added it back), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76654238/spring-boot-kafka-how-to-dynamically-increase-decrease-consumer-thread-count/76654319#76654319) and its comments for links to a bunch of answers showing several techniques for adding consumers dynamically, using Spring.

Comment: The question was also tagged `python`, so neither seemed relevant

Comment: Good point; I am just answering from a Spring perspective.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I do appreciate your work here - your broader Kafka knowledge probably exceeds mine, but you do also seem to have a good grasp of the Spring value add too.