# Spring boot kafka how to dynamically increase/decrease consumer thread count

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have one kafka topic with some high number of partitions, say 100 **(fixed)**, and I have a spring boot application which has kafka listeners(or say consumer) consuming from the topic. Now I know that using `concurrency` property you can adjust the number of consumer threads, something like this (controlling it via `application.properties` file):

```
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "${someGroupID}",
            topics = "${someTopic}",
            containerFactory = "someKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            concurrency = "${concurrencyProperty}")
    {
            //some logic
    }
```

Using `concurrency` property on `@KafkaListener` I can fix the number of consumer threads but if I want to dynamically adjust that number during runtime based on the request load (say if all consumer threads are occupied, render 5 new consumer threads), is there anyway to do this?

Or let me know if there are any better practices to manage the consumer threads according to the load. Thanks.

***NOTE:*** I have kept topic **partition count as fixed** to a **high number** since increasing that number could bring in consumer re-balancing delays which as far as I know can be very time consuming, so I am planning to keep the partition count as fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the `concurrency` dynamically while the container is running; you can, however, stop the container, change the `concurrency` and restart it.

To stop/start the container, use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean, and give the listener(s) an `id` property so you can get a reference to the specific container from the registry.

You should not stop a container on one of its listener threads.

Comment: Would this approach be better or maybe assigning the task to be executed to a dynamic ExecutorThreadPool? Restarting a container would have some overheads i think...

Comment: No; it is not good practice to consume records asynchronously. Another alternative would be to add more containers dynamically. Search here; there are several ways to create containers dynamically. See this answer for some links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471941/spring-kafka-multiple-topic-for-one-class-dynamically/71483489#71483489

Comment: This might be the simplest approach - make the listener a prototype bean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744775/can-i-add-topics-to-my-kafkalistener-at-runtime/68745230#68745230

Comment: My requirement was more like fire and forget, so thought async consumption would also be fine. But thanks for the links, surely will check those out!